# Alternative to Visual Studio Debugger for programming C++ & SDL2 in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, game-development, visual-studio, debugging

I'm looking for an alternative program or plugin for an IDE that can be used for cross-platform compilation of SDL2 projects written in C++ to these platforms:

- Windows
- Linux
- Raspbian
- BSD
- Android

The alternative should have a hex editor like Visual Studio Debugger does, Autos, Locals, Watch and Globals. It should have the option to set breakpoints, step in/out/next through the code, seek expressions (like `&foo` or `&(mario->xposition)`) in hex editor. Classes, structures and arrays should have collapsable trees to see parameters. Variables should show addresses that are enterable into the hex editor.

CodeBlocks has some problems and doesn't work like Visual Studio. The reason I'm avoiding Visual Studio is to enable cross-platform compatibility and to avoid licensing issues when using the VS runtime and also because I'm moving to Ubuntu.

What is the closest program that can fulfill these requirements?